# ASP.NET Reportviewer shows reports when i use sessionstate "InProc" but does not when i use "StateServer"

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, session-state

I  have my asp.net state service enabled and configured my session state config as per below but my reports keep saying "***ASP.NET session has expired***" when i try to generate my reports using reportviewer (I am using VS2005):

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="80"/>
```

Now, it does work when using in process session state as follows:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="80"/>
```

I want to use StateServer out-of-process session state but my reports always expire. Any idea why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reportviewer should still work using StateServer as stated on this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251661%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). To use StateServer, the "ASP.NET State Service" must be running.

Comment: Hi Hallie, thanks for your answer. Indeed this should work but it doesn't. My asp.net state service is running too.

Comment: Are you using any session object? If yes, what are you putting in the session?

Comment: 15 Session variables of which: 1 datatable and all the rest built-in types - string * 8, Int32 * 3, Boolean * 3.

Comment: @Zen : check your impersonation settings.

Comment: some people encounter's the same issue, check this out (http://forums.asp.net/p/1238835/2671891.aspx), it might help you.

Comment: Hi Hallie thanks for the help, opted to not use StateServer for the particular part that does not work.